# Why is this cross-cast not allowed?

Tags: c++, static-cast, cross-cast

Consider this simple example:

```
struct Base1 {};

struct Base2 {};

struct Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {};

int main()
{
   Derived foo;
   Base1* foo1 = &foo;
   Base2* foo2 =  static_cast<Base2*>(foo1); 
}
```

I get:

```
Error: static_cast from 'Base1 *' to 'Base2 *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
```

The compiler should have enough information to figure out that `Base2` can be reached from `Derived`  without RTTI (`dynamic_cast`) and having me to do:

```
Derived* foo3 = static_cast<Derived*>(foo1);
Base2* foo2 = foo3;
```

Why isn't this allowed? (One could argue that the compiler doesn't know if `foo1` is of `Derived` type, but `static_cast` doesn't check the type anyway even when converting from `Base1` to `Derived` for example)

*Note: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810204/cross-cast-attempt-using-static-cast-failing-why) is similiar to mine, but it's not quite the same because here we are cross-casting base classes, not derived ones*

Comment: It's totally not a good idea to cast from Base1 to Base2 IMHO. why would you like to do this? don't waste time.

Comment: Imagine you're a compiler, how would you fulfill the request "convert `0x123456`, a `Base1 *`, to a `Base2 *`. What's the resulting address and how did you work it out?

Comment: In a different file you might have 
`struct Derived2 : public Base2, public Base1 {};` so the compiler cannot do any assumption based on `Derived` alone.

Comment: The `Derived` memory layout is known to the compiler, so it could cast `Base1` to `Base2` without problems. (Assuming `Base1` is actually `Derived` of course). I think what Johannes said is probably the real reason it doesn't make this assumption. (And the reason why `Base1` and `Base2` are treated as not related)

Comment: Why assume Base1 is actually Derived? There might be various other classes that have Base1 and Base2 as bases in different layouts.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what Johannes said. I got it now thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static_cast` will fail since, informally speaking, `Base1` and `Base2` are not related.

However a `dynamic_cast` will work if your classes are *polymorphic*: which you can achieve by adding virtual destructors:

```
struct Base1 {virtual ~Base1() = default;};

struct Base2 {virtual ~Base2() = default;};

struct Derived : Base1, Base2 {};

int main()
{
   Derived foo;
   Base1* foo1 = &foo;
   Base2* foo2 =  dynamic_cast<Base2*>(foo1); 
}
```

This casting from `Base1` to `Base2` is idiomatic when working with *composition* (i.e. interfaces).